# Exceptions Error on double - Could not be set to a "System.Single"

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an exceptions on my model.

```
public double? Priority { get; set; }
```

I have changed this from `double`, `Double`, and `double?` And I am still getting this error. In my SQL table this is set to `float`. Which should match the `double`.

The complete error I am getting:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Priority' property on 'MySitemap' could not be set to a 'System.Single' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Double'. '

Update:

The code that is doing this is just a simple index list:

```
 // GET: Sitemap
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Sitemaps.ToList());
    }
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MySitemap](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Location] [varchar](500) NULL,
[ChangeFreq] [varchar](20) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MySitemap_ChangeFreq]  DEFAULT ('daily'),
[Priority] [float](5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MySitemap_Priority]  DEFAULT ((0.5)),
[LastModified] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MySitemap_LastMod] DEFAULT GETDATE(),
[Category] [varchar](50) NULL,
[IsAdded] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MySitemap_IsAdded] DEFAULT ('False'),
CONSTRAINT [PK_MySitemap] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON 
[PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Can you show the code that actually replicates this? Perhaps a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Maybe also include your table definition, too.

Comment: Is this db first or code first?

Comment: @tymtam this is code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `[Priority] [float](5)`

Maps to System.Single, not System.Double:

> Syntax
>
> float [ (n) ] Where n is the number of bits that are used to
>   store the mantissa of the float number in scientific notation and,
>   therefore, dictates the precision and storage size. If n is specified,
>   it must be a value between 1 and 53. The default value of n is 53.
>
> `n value  Precision   Storage size 
>   1-24    7 digits    4 bytes 
>   25-53   15 digits   8 bytes`

[float and real (TSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks for that. I changed this originally was using a string. Did not realize that it did not need the (5) after it. Problem solved by removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the db side is not of type `real`?

For this error, the solution is to make `Priority` be a `float`.

Comment: Really sure as i am the one who created the table.. Edited above

Comment: Ha! So it was a float but a float(5).